# Guaranteeing that three straight lines form a triangle in the third quadrant

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, systems-of-equations

The points of intersection of the following three straight lines form a triangle with all of the vertices in the third quadrant.

$x-2y=1$
$y-4x=3$
$3y+2x=-19$

How can we guarantee that any three lines will intersect to form a triangle with all of its vertices in the third quadrant?

I have explored looking at the gradients, $x$-intercepts and $y$-intercepts, as well as looking at the forming the equations of the lines given the points, but I'm wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: if there are 3 distinct intersection points you have a triangle

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for a way of guaranteeing that all the vertices are in the third quadrant.

Comment: The simplest solution appears to be to choose the three vertices first.

Comment: if you find where the intersection points are you can determine if they are in the third quadrant or not.

Answer (score 1):

The following analysis is an *attempt* to show what happens if you look
for an alternative approach to computing the vertices directly.

> Constraint-1: $~x-2y=1$ 
> Constraint-2: $~y-4x=3$ 
> Constraint-3: $~3y+2x=-19$

There are two issues:

- Show that if $x \geq 0$, it is impossible to find any value
  for $y$ that satisfies at least two of the pertinent constraints.
- Show that if $y \geq 0$, it is impossible to find any value
  for $x$ that satisfies at least two of the pertinent constraints.

Setting $x \geq 0$:

$1 + 2y \geq 0 \implies y \geq (-1/2).$

$y - 3 \geq 0 \implies y \geq 3.$

$-19 - 3y \geq 0 \implies 3y + 19 \leq 0 \implies y \leq (-19/3).$

It is immediate that only the 1st and 2nd constraints need be considered.

At this point, I see no alternative to multiplying the 2nd constraint by 2,
and then comparing it with the 1st constraint.  I consider
this approach *out-of-bounds* because you are (in effect) descending to
solving for the specific values of $x$, $y$.

---

Contrast this with the alternative query: show that **at least two** of
the vertices must lie in the 3rd quadrant.  With the alternative query,
considering the specific assumption of $(x \geq 0)$, it would have been sufficient to show, as I did, that when
$x \geq 0$, Constraint-3 is incompatible with both Constraint-1 and Constraint-2.

Exploring this alternative query, with respect to setting $y \geq 0$:

$x - 1 \geq 0 \implies x \geq 1.$

$3 + 4x \geq 0 \implies x \geq (-3/4).$

$-19 - 2x \geq 0 \implies 2x + 19 \leq 0 \implies x \leq (-19/2).$

**Again**, Constraint-3 is incompatible with both Constraint-1 and Constraint-2.

Assume that the 3 equations can be *solved* to generate 3 vertices.  Consider the incompatibility of Constraint-3 with the other two constraints, when **either** $x \geq 0$ **or** $y \geq 0$.  Because of these incompatibilities, you immediately know,
without *solving* for any of the vertices, that **at least two** of the vertices must lie in the 3rd quadrant.

As I see it, identifying the location of the vertex that corresponds to Constraint-1 and Constraint-2 will require descent into the normal methods.

Answer (score 0):

Choose minimum  values ( say -6 each ) for coordinates  $x,y$  ( domains/range) as minimum to include all desired vertices.

$$ 0<x<x_{min}  \text{; and } 0<y<y_{min}; $$

All coordinates points $x,y$ .should be non-positive.